install packages in ubuntu 24.04 server from list in text file
I recently did a clean install of ubuntu 24.04 server.  Previously I had been running ubuntu server 18.04.  Before I did the clean install of ubuntu 24.04 I exported the list of packages I had installed to a file called installed_packages.txt.  It has entries like the example below.  I would like to try to install all the packages in the installed_packages.txt file in my new ubuntu server 24.04 and save a list of any packages that failed to be installed in a new file called failed_install.txt.  Is there a way I can install packages in ubuntu server 24.04 server from a text file like the installed_packages.txt file?  For example is there some command I could run in terminal?
example installed_packages.txt:

accountsservice     install
acl                 install
acpid               install


What command did you use to do the export?

Personally I would question trying to install all the same packages from an old version of Ubuntu into the latest version.

That looks like the format used by the dpkg command's --get-selections / --set-selections however I'm not sure its safe (or even possible) to use it across different major releases. See also 'Package not in database' when restoring with dpkg --set-selections .

You are making a huge jump from 18.04 to 24.04. I would advise against trying to install the same packages by their (maybe now old) name. You probably want to look into functionality that you want in your new server "as it was" on your old machine. For example, in 18.04 you would use ifconfig to show your network configuration, in recent version, you would use ip. If you would still want the previous functionality, you would have to manually add the package net-tools. Install you new machine "clean" and then add functionality as you need it by using all relevant new packages.
